# how to fix request matching Date time error in query params wiremock

Tags: java, json, datetime, wiremock, wiremock-standalone

Why am i getting request match error in wiremock

```
"request": {
    "method": "GET",
    "urlPath": "/abc/v1",

    "queryParams": {
      "FromDate": {
        "equalToDateTime": "now -1 months",
        "actualFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "truncateExpected": "first hour of day"
      },

      "ToDate": {
        "equalToDateTime": "now -1 days",
        "actualFormat": "dd/MM/yyyy",
        "truncateExpected": "first hour of day"
      }
    }
  }
```

i get the following error

```
Query: FromDate [equalToDateTime] now -1 months<<<<< Query does not match
Query: ToDate [equalToDateTime] now -1 days<<<<< Query does not match
```

The data  type for FromDate and ToDate is **org.joda.time.LocalDate;**

Comment: What does your request look like?

I would be worried about [timezones](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/70c32a330f2fdbc2748bcb4e25c09fa42af637fe/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/matching/EqualToDateTimePattern.java#L79) like `now` on the wiremock server might be a different day than you expect. Also maybe there's some difference in your interpretation of `now -1 months`? Here's how wiremock is [shifting time](https://github.com/wiremock/wiremock/blob/70c32a330f2fdbc2748bcb4e25c09fa42af637fe/src/main/java/com/github/tomakehurst/wiremock/common/DateTimeOffset.java#L79).

Comment: Can you share the full request you're making?

This one worked for me:
`http://localhost:8080/abc/v1?FromDate=23/05/2022&ToDate=22/06/2022`

Comment: My full request is :   localhost:8080/abc/v1?FromDate=2022-05-23&ToDate=2022-06-23 – 2022 and Here the data type  of FromDate and ToDate is of type org.joda.time.LocalDate;